# subplots_adjust with seaborn.regplot

Tags: seaborn

when using `seaborn.regplot`, the xlabel and ylabel and yticklabels are actually cut off, i.e., not visible. Normall, I'd do

```
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.subplots_adjust(left=...)
```

to fix this. However, this doesn't seem to have any impact on the figure.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, unfortunately. It's going to be fixed in 0.3, but there's no easy way to fix it with the current version (`subplots_adjust` and `tight_layout` don't work because they underlying axes aren't on a subplot grid). You could grab the axes objects from `fig.axes` and move them with `ax.set_position()`, but it won't be pretty.

For a similar plot that should be better behaved, you could use `seaborn.lmplot`, if you don't need the marginal histograms.

Edit to say I wrote up a more complete solution [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/114).

```
sns.regplot(x, y, xlabel="x", ylabel="y")
axj, axx, axy = plt.gcf().axes
axj.set_position([.12, .12, .7, .7])
axx.set_position([.12, .85, .7, .13])
axy.set_position([.85, .12, .13, .7])
```

Comment: thanks! of course not the answer I was hoping for, but great to hear from you. I really like seaborn, I think the plots look awesome!